# can anyone explain to me why is this assembly code not working?

Tags: assembly, nasm, microcontroller

so we have a microcontroller with a keyboard and a screen and LED'S

var nokey define that no key was pressed, ppi_pa3 is a speaker, keybd is the keyboard
when i press any key the micro controller notice it and actually display that on the leds (executed in line 71)
then if the key is pressed status get the value 1 and the isr_freqtimer should be executed but it is not working can anyone please help

```
        org 100h
        cpu 8086

        jmp start

; Variablen

status  db 00000000b    ; Statusbyte
;                 ^
;                 |
;                 +-----> Ton (1, an) / (0, aus)

; Konstanten
intab0      equ 20h     ; Adresse Interrupttabelle PIT, Kanal 1
intab1      equ intab0 + 1 * 4  ; Adresse Interrupttabelle PIT, Kanal 2
intab7      equ intab0 + 7 * 4  ; Adresse Interrupttabelle Lichttaster
eoi         equ 20h     ; End Of Interrupt (EOI)
clrscr      equ 0       ; Clear Screen
getkey      equ 1       ; Funktion auf Tastatureingabe warten
ascii       equ 2       ; Funktion ASCII-Zeichenausgabe
hexbyte     equ 4       ; HEX-Byte Ausgabe
conin       equ 5       ; Console IN
conout      equ 6       ; Console OUT
pitc        equ 0a6h    ; Steuerkanal PIT
pit1        equ 0a2h    ; Counter 1 PIT
pit2        equ 0a4h    ; Counter 2 PIT
ppi_ctl     equ 0b6h    ; Steuerkanal PPI (Parallelinterface)
ppi_a       equ 0b0h    ; Kanal A PPI
ppi_pa0     equ 1       ; LED 0
ppi_pa1     equ 2       ; LED 1
ppi_pa2     equ 4       ; LED 2
ppi_pa3     equ 8       ; Lautsprecher
ppi_pa6     equ 1 << 6  ; Servomotor
ppi_b       equ 0b2h    ; Kanal B PPI
ppi_c       equ 0b4h    ; Kanal C PPI
ocw_2_3     equ 0c0h    ; PIC (Interruptcontroller), OCW2,3
ocw_1       equ 0c2h    ; PIC (Interruptcontroller), OCW1
icw_1       equ 0c0h    ; PIC (Interruptcontroller), ICW1
icw_2_4     equ 0c2h    ; PIC (Interruptcontroller), ICW2,4
leds        equ 0       ; LED Port
schalter    equ 0       ; Schalterport
keybd       equ 80h     ; SBC-86 Tastatur
gokey       equ 11h     ; Taste "GO"
outkey      equ 15h     ; Taste "OUT"
sseg7       equ 9eh     ; Segmentanzeige 7
tcfreq      equ 440     ; initiale Frequenz
basefreq    equ 1843200 ; Basistakt in Hz
nokey       equ 7       ; keine Taste gedrueckt

start:

; Initialisierung

    mov ah, clrscr      ; Anzeige aus
    int conout
    
    mov byte [status], 0    ; Init. Statusbyte und alle LEDs
    mov al, 0
    out ppi_a, al
    out leds, al

    call init,          ; Controller und Interruptsystem scharfmachen
    
; Hintergrundprogramm (ist immer aktiv, wenn im Service nichts zu tun ist)
; Hier sollten Ausgaben auf das Display getätigt werden, Tastatureingaben, etc.

again:

; Code des Hintergrundprogammes
    in al,keybd
    out 0,al
    mov ah,al
    and ah, nokey
    cmp ah,7
    je silence
    or byte[status],1
    jmp again

silence:
    and byte[status], ~1    
    jmp again

        
; Initialisierung Controller und Interruptsystem

init:
    cli         ; Interrupts aus

; PIT-Init.

;   Nichts zu tun, das macht die Main-Loop :-)
;   mov al, 01110110b   ; Kanal 1, Mode 3, 16-Bit ZK
;   out pitc, al        ; Steuerkanal
;   mov al, tcfreq & 0ffh   ; Low-Teil Zeitkonstante
;   out pit1, al
;   mov al, tcfreq >> 8 ; High-Teil Zeitkonstante
;   out pit1, al

; PPI-Init.
    mov al, 10001011b   ; PPI A/B/C Mode 0, A Output, sonst Input
    out ppi_ctl, al
    jmp short $+2       ; I/O-Delay
    mov al, 0           ; LED's aus (high aktiv)
    out ppi_a, al
    
; PIC-Init.
    mov al, 00010011b   ; ICW1, ICW4 benoetigt, Bit 2 egal, 
                        ; Flankentriggerung
    out icw_1, al
    jmp short $+2       ; I/O-Delay
    mov al, 00001000b   ; ICW2, auf INT 8 gemapped
    out icw_2_4, al
    jmp short $+2       ; I/O-Delay
    mov al, 00010001b   ; ICW4, MCS-86, EOI, non-buffered,
                ; fully nested
    out icw_2_4, al
    jmp short $+2       ; I/O-Delay
    mov al, 11111110b   ; Kanal 0, 1 + 7 am PIC demaskieren
                        ; PIT K1
    out ocw_1, al
    
; Interrupttabelle init.    
    
    mov word [intab0], isr_freqtimer    ; Interrupttabelle (Timer K1) 
                        ; initialisieren (Offset)
    mov [intab0 + 2], cs        ; (Segmentadresse)
    
    sti                 ; ab jetzt Interrupts
    ret

;------------------------ Serviceroutine -----------------------------------
    
isr_freqtimer:              ; Timer fuer Lautsprecher
    push ax
    test byte[status],1
    jz isr_freqtimer_out
    in al, ppi_a
    xor al, ppi_pa3
    out ppi_a,al


; Code der Serviceroutine fuer die Lautsprecherausgabe  
    
isr_freqtimer_out:      ; Ausgang aus dem Service
    mov al, eoi         ; EOI an PIC
    out ocw_2_3, al
    pop ax
    iret

;Frequenzen in zwei Oktaven von c4 bis b5 in Hertz (Hz)

tonleiter:
    dw 262 ; c4   0
    dw 277 ; c#4  1
    dw 294 ; d4   2 
    dw 311 ; d#4  3
    dw 329 ; e4   4
    dw 349 ; f4   5
    dw 370 ; f#4  6
    dw 392 ; g4   7
    dw 415 ; g#4  8
    dw 440 ; a4   9
    dw 466 ; a#4  10
    dw 493 ; b4   11
    dw 523 ; c5   12
    dw 554 ; c#5  13 
    dw 587 ; d5   14
    dw 622 ; d#5  15
    dw 659 ; e5   16
    dw 698 ; f5   17 
    dw 740 ; f#5  18
    dw 784 ; g5   19
    dw 830 ; g#5  20
    dw 880 ; a5   21
    dw 932 ; a#5  22 
    dw 987 ; b5   23
```

Comment: Do you have a simulator for this microcontroller, or any other way to single-step the code?  This is [a lot of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) for a [mcve], not a great fit for Stack Overflow.  Especially if you can't narrow down the possible problem any more than "[it's not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)".  What *is* working?  What have you been able to figure out with your debugging efforts so far?  Which line is line 71?

Comment: yeah, i have a simulator for this one, so init function is working the loop is working, and pressing a key is working it actually changes the status byte to 1 but i have no sound coming out of it. sadly the simulator does not produce any sounds

Comment: The simulator should have a debugger, or a way to act as a remote for GDB.  So you can single-step the code and see what's happening to registers, and what instructions are executing.  This is essential for debugging asm, *way* easier than reading through the whole source and trying to check every possible problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes i can see what's happening the register actually changes but i don't understand how is the isr_freqtimer function supposed to run. maybe you can help me understand it?

Comment: I mean look at the CPU registers, like AX and CX, and follow the path of execution to see what your code is doing.

Comment: ` test byte[status],1` `jz isr_freqtimer_out` needs a CS: segment override prefix: ` test byte[cs: status],1` `jz isr_freqtimer_out`

Comment: Remember that sound hardware is especially difficult to debug, since most sound chips have a pitch range that's much wider than what we can hear. You need to be intimately familiar with the particular sound chip you're using to properly operate it. I can say from experience that this is no easy task. Not to discourage you, I'm saying this because knowing how to debug is an important skill, and for sound hardware even more so.